# Putting string from resource between single quotes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, localization

I have

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" value="<%$ Resources: WebResource, Search %>" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Search';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search') this.value='';" />
```

How can I do something like this for onblur

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" value="<%$ Resources: WebResource, Search %>" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='<%=Resources.WebResource.Search %>';" onfocus="if(this.value=='<%=Resources.WebResource.Search %') this.value='';" />
```

to localize JavaScript inline?

Comment: Thanks Darin, something wrong was with my Google Chrome filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use databinding expressions (`<%# %>`):

```
<asp:TextBox 
    runat="server" 
    ID="TextBox1" 
    value="<%$ Resources: WebResource, Search %>" 
    onblur='<%# string.Format("if(this.value==\"\") this.value=\"{0}\"", Resources.WebResource.Search) %>'
    onfocus='<%# string.Format("if(this.value==\"{0}\") this.value=\"\"", Resources.WebResource.Search) %>'
/>
```

Make sure you call `DataBind` on the page. Or in the code behind:

```
TextBox1.Attributes["onblur"] = string.Format("if(this.value==\"\") this.value=\"{0}\"", Resources.WebResource.Search);
TextBox1.Attributes["onfocus"] = string.Format("if(this.value==\"{0}\") this.value=\"\"", Resources.WebResource.Search);
```